# Symfony 6. Relacional query using findBy()

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I have 2 tables, "A" and "B", I need a query to get all "A" how "B" are "private". (relation
`ManyToOne`
)

Can a make that search using

```
findBy()
```

from the Symfony? Or a need to use

```
createQuery()
```

My problem is if I use createQuery(), works fine, but the problem is, the fields from the data are different from the findBy(), and if I what to have the same fields I need to write too much code.

in my EntityRepository.php

```
public function findBy(array $criteria, ?array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
    {
        $persister = $this->_em->getUnitOfWork()->getEntityPersister($this->_entityName);

        return $persister->loadAll($criteria, $orderBy, $limit, $offset);
    }
```

I made the

```
createQuery()
```

but the data´s fields are different

I think the difference is because when I use `findBy()` the annotation `#[Ignore]` in the `Entity` get called, and when I use the `createQuery()` is ignored.

Comment: you have to add `oneToMany` property in car entity and that it's getter, add and remove method....after that you can get all clients which has car red from car entity

Comment: Avoid using images in questions.  Code blocks work much better.  And you probably need to take the time to work through some of the basic examples in the docs.  To answer your question, no you cannot use findBy for this sort of query.  You will need to use one of the various approaches to generating a query as described in the docs.

Comment: @RaviDamasiya thanks, I change my question, sorry, my 1st question is in StackOverflow. I need to send the "B" (Car) table information inside of an "A" (Client) Object. I think if I do what you said is going to be, "A"( Car) inside of "B" (Client). And i know know Why the Data is different, is because i have `#[Ignore]` annotation.